# python Tkinter not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to use python Tkinter lib but it's not working and I don't know why.
I am using python version 3.4.3 in windows 8.1. When it didn't work the first time I did some research and found some articles suggesting ActivePython bee installed. After further inspection on ActiveState website, I found out that I already TK based on my python version but it doesn't work when I tried to use it in my first application. When I checked my lib folder in my python installation I saw tkinter and tried the test programs but the windows disappears instantly. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please show us some code. Please describe what "not working" means: is your computer crashing? Are you getting an error? What error?

Comment: Do you call the `mainloop` function of the root window in your script?

Answer (score 1):

Try if you have tkinter installed to cmd write

```
py -m pip install tkinter
```

and

```
pip install tkinter
```

Next step is -> in python file:

```
from tkinter import *
```

or

```
import tkinter
tkinter.exaplecommand
```

Comment: **This is wrong. Do not use `pip` to try to solve this problem. No part of the standard library can properly be obtained from PyPI.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your situation but a possible answer is you are importing Tkinter not tkinter. In Python 3 you need to import a lowercase tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x it is

```
from tkinter import*
```

In Python 2.x it is

```
from Tkinter import*
```