# Python tkinter installation failing initial test

Tags: tkinter, installation

I'm trying to get off the ground with tkinter, running Python 3.11.0 on Windows 11.

Tkinter and ttk are supposed to come packaged with Python 3.1 and up.
Nevertheless, when I run the test for a successful installation, Python simply hangs.

I'm in my VS Code codespace in Harvard's GitHub container for registrants in the course CS50P, so I didn't have to download Python, am just using what's provided. I would have thought everything there was up to date, but maybe a manual installation of tkinter is needed?

Code lines below pasted from the TkDocs Tutorial, page on installing tkinter:

```
$ python
Python 3.11.0 (main, Nov 29 2022, 18:19:24) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```

Expected result (from TkDocs Tutorial): "This should pop up a small window; the first line at the top of the window should say, "This is Tcl/Tk version 8.6".

Actual result: No tkinter window pops up as expected, yet neither is there an error message to say "No module named tkinter". Just a static cursor at the bottom of my code. To get out, I have to terminate Python with Ctrl + z.

Suggestions from [python Tkinter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620927/python-tkinter-not-working):

```
$ py -m pip install tkinter
bash: py: command not found
CS50P/project/ $ pip install tkinter
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

What, then, are the steps? TkDocs Tutorial assumes all will be well and gives no further help with this problem.

Comment: `tkinter` cannot be installed by `pip`. You need to select `tkinter` when installing Python in Windows platform.

Comment: My opening sentence may be inaccurate. My own machine runs Windows 11, but I believe Harvard CS50 runs Python in the cloud on Linux.

Comment: When you enter `py --version` at the terminal prompt, what do you see? (note that `py` is the Windows convention; you might want to also try `python --version`)

Comment: Then I don't think you can run tkinter GUI application in cloud environment.

Comment: _" I believe Harvard CS50 runs Python in the cloud on Linux."_ - if that's the case, it's doubtful tkinter will work. Tkinter requires a display.

Comment: Response to JRiggles:CS50P/project/ $ py --version
bash: py: command not found
CS50P/project/ $ python --version
Python 3.11.0
CS50P/project/ $